# How to determine if my application was launched through click on application or click on a document?

Tags: java, macos, deployment, installation, command-line-arguments

I have a Java application which gets deployed as an Application Bundle on Mac OS X. I modified the info.plist to register for file types I can handle and use eAWT to register various Listeners (`AppForegroundListener, AppReOpenedListener, OpenFilesHandler, OpenURIHandler, AppHiddenListener`).

My application should work in the following way:

- If started by clicking on the Application a "New Document Wizard" guides the user through creating a new Document.
- If the user click on a document and uses "Open With" my application should open that document and not do the wizard thing.

My Problem:

How do I determine whether my application was started by clicking on a document or on the application?

- `args[]` from `main(String[] args)` is always empty no matter how the Application was started
- If the application was started through a document click, my listener gets called. If it was started directly no event seems to be called - and unless I pop up some GUI the application terminates.
- I can use the deprecated method `addApplicationListener`. In this case I get an *application opened* event, but this event is delivered in either case and before the *open file* event and thus also not helpful.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but this would be trivial if launched using JWS - the argument array to main would contain at least two arguments when opened via a file association.

Comment: I might use some kind of timeout in the `main` method (launched off in it's own thread).  This should give time for the listener to pick up any requests.  If no request is received within the timeout period, assume a normal launch

Comment: @AndrewThompson unfortunately JWS comes with its own bag of problems; mostly browsers doing their best to dissuade people from using the application - sometimes in very strong words, e.g. Chrome. I actually do have JWS at the moment, but want to move to App bundle to avoid the JWS problems.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I'll use this as a last resort. It will be tricky to set the timeout long enough to be very sure its not a "open document" but short enough to not annoy the user on a normal start.